# How to mock imported module class in pytest

Tags: pytest, monkeypatching, pytest-mock

I have this files.

- main.py
- util.py
- mocking_util.py
- test_main.py

I'd like to use mocking_util.py instead of util.py in test code.

I know mocker.patch("util.my_something1", return_value = 1)
but it only works at function level.

How can I mock an entire module?

main.py

```
from . import util.py

def something1(a, b):
    return util.my_something(a, b)

def something2(a, b):
    return util.my_something2(a, b)

def something3(a, b):
    return util.my_something3(a, b)
```

util.py

```
def my_something1(a, b):
    return a + b

def my_something2(a, b):
    return a + b + 1

def my_something3(a, b):
    return a + b + 2
```

mocking_util.py

```
def my_something1(a, b):
    return 1

def my_something2(a, b):
    return 1

def my_something2(a, b):
    return 1
```

test_main.py

```
import main

def test_case1(mocker):
    # I'd like to use mocking_util.py instead of util.py
    # What should I do for this?

    result = main.something1(10, 10)
    assert result == 1

    result = main.something2(10, 10)
    assert result == 1

    result = main.something3(10, 10)
    assert result == 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using pytest-mock

`pip install pytest-mock`

### Patch the `util` module in the `main` module with `mocking_util`

```py
import main
import mocking_util


def test_case1(mocker):
    
    mocker.patch('main.util', mocking_util)
```

The `mocker` fixture allows you to access the [unittest.mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) symbol.

> unittest.mock.patch(target, new=DEFAULT, spec=None, create=False, spec_set=None, autospec=None, new_callable=None, **kwargs)
>
> > The target is imported and the specified object replaced with the new object [passed in `new`].

### Now when `main` calls `util.my_something`, it will call `mocking_util.my_something`

```py
    
    result = main.something1(10, 10)
    assert result == 1

    result = main.something2(10, 10)
    assert result == 1

    result = main.something3(10, 10)
    assert result == 1
```